# Removing block-system-main div from content

Tags: blocks, nodes

I'm building a website where I output some of the markup to the front page via `hook_page_alter()`, and the rest via `hook_menu()` calling a form. I have a local version running on my laptop that is working fine. The problem is that in the remote install, Drupal is adding the divs:

```
<div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system first last odd">
  <div class="content"> 
     //My form markup is in here
  </div>
</div>
//The hook_page_alter markup is in here.
```

This way, the submit button is always on top of the rest of the content and I would like to be on the bottom. The local install of Drupal doesn't do this for some reason.

Does anyone know how to:

- get rid of the two divs (I know I can do it in block.tpl.php with a block--content.tpl.php) but maybe something cleaner would be nice
- (or, ideally) how to add the content from `hook_page_alter()` to the same div as the form is in

In `hook_menu()` I'm just doing a standard call to `drupal_get_form()`. Here's the code for `hook_page_alter()`:

```
function planb_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 
    $q = db_query('SELECT name, mname, number_of_instances FROM {event_type} ORDER BY        number_of_instances DESC');
    foreach($q as $event) {
      $options['name'][] = $event->name;
      $options['mname'][] = $event->mname;
    }
    $tri = array(
      '#theme' => 'frontpage_canvas',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#weight' => -1000,
    );
    return $page['content']['triangle'] = $tri;
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's working locally but not remotely, then it makes me believe that this is going to have something to do with the database which your local Drupal install is using. Have you tried checking out if you've removed said content from the main Drupal Admin page (content/blocks)?

Comment: Well, the thing is I don't want to remove this content because the form generated is being rendered in the content block. The problem is that the content created by hook_page_alter() isn't getting added to the content block - but it is getting added to the content region, if that makes any sense. Because if I change the region where the content is displayed to, say, the footer, the form will move there but the markup generated by hook_page_alter() will stay where it is. However, to answer your question, yes, the Admin section is the same for both installs. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Is there a good reason you are using a page_alter? Due to its global nature, I think it should be used only as a very last resort. It would be more interesting with a question that focuses on how to git rid of it.

Comment: `hook_page_alter()` doesn't return any value.